# IE11 security problem when testing external links against RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am using the following JQuery code to make sure that external links open in a new tab on my website:

```
    $('a:not(.magnific-video)').each(function () {
        var extLink = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
        if (!extLink.test(this.href)) { // IE11 throws the security problem here
            $(this).click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                window.open(this.href, '_blank');
            });
        }
    });
```

This works perfectly in all browsers except for Internet Explorer. Weirdly, this script runs on every page of my website but the error only occurs on the contact page (in IE11). When I load the contact page, I get a `SCRIPT14: A security problem occured.` error in the console which points to the line that I have commented in the code above (the line with `.test()`) and none of the other javascript on the page works. All pages on my site have external links (in the footer and elsewhere) and so the only difference between other pages and the contact page is that it loads google maps via their API to display a map on the page (maybe that has something to do with it as it's the only noticeable difference compared to the other pages).

**What I'm looking for**

A fix for the security problem in Internet Explorer so that all of the other scripts on the contact page work as they do in the other browsers.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

I replaced my script above with the following that I found on GitHub. It seems to do the same thing and I no longer get the security problem on IE11... not a solution to the script above not working hence why I'm not putting it as an answer.

```
$('a:not(.magnific-video)')
    .filter('[href^="http"], [href^="//"]')
    .not('[href*="' + window.location.host + '"]')
    .attr('rel', 'noopener noreferrer')
    .attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: Your regex does not appear to be doing anything fancy, why not perform the string search with `if (this.href.indexOf(window.location.host) < 0 ...` instead?

Comment: @AlexK. I still get the security issue when I replace the regex with that code :/

Comment: What does a failing url look like?

Comment: @AlexK. the security problem doesn't happen when I click a link, but when the page loads so I don't think it's to do with any of the links, but a link that meets that condition is any link that doesn't have 'websitename.com' in it, i.e. a link to 'google.com' would pass the if statement, but 'websitename.com/contact' wouldn't

Comment: Strange, does it still happen if you `var x = this.href;` then `.test(x)` ?

Comment: I guess the browser is actually complaining about the `$(this).click()` part.

Comment: Have you ever tried to use F12 developer tools to check the value (extLink and this.href)? Please check it and share the related value so that we could test it on our side.